# How to move cursor to first word inside quotes?

Tags: vim, neovim

I want to move cursor to `content`. I'm using `^` to move to first non-whitespace character, `w` to first word.

```
<div class="container">
|   <div class="content">
        <p>I love you.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The pipe (`|`) shows the cursor position. How can I move it to `content` word? Like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="|content">
        <p>I love you.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on a little but on what you want to do, but basically this can be done with:

```
f"w
```

<kbd>f</kbd> jumps to the char specified next, so <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> jumps to the first quote, and the following <kbd>w</kbd> moves to the next word.
But usually you don't just want to go there, if you want to insert a word before "content", you can do it directly with:

```
f"a
```

If you want to change the content inside the quote just do the following:

```
ci"
```

Vim will automatically jump to the next quote.

There are more similar commands, so you should tell us what you want to do exactly!

Comment: yeah, that is correct. have also a look at `t` which does the same, but places the cursor before the searched char. extremly usefull for manipulation commands like "delete everything until the first equal sign" -> `dt=` will leave the equal sign intact, while `df=` will delete also the sign.

Comment: Thank you. I guess `f"ci"` is the best solution for me. edit: Sorry I deleted my previous comment accidentally. :)

Comment: No, if you want to do a `ci"` do it directly, vim automatically jumps to the next quote. No need for a `f"` there

Comment: Wooaaaw. I'm enlightened. How I can't realize it... Thank you again. But `f` is useful too.

Comment: Glad i could help you. `f` and also `t` are really common in my vim workflow (and i think the same goes for most people) so try to make use of them. Have fun ;-)

Comment: Just another hint, you can also use a count with `f` and `t` so `2fa` will jump to the second `a`. And `F` and `T` will search backwards

Answer (score 0):

If you're not on the right line, you can search with: `/".\{-}\<\zs\w`